# MTd Vs MDd - Static linking win32 library in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qmake, static-linking

I have a static library built with Visual Studio as a static library (built with Run Time Librbary:Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)). But when I am using it in my QT project, it says mismatch.

```
xerces-c_static_3d.lib(XMLString.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in helloworld.obj
```

Relevant `Makefile.Debug` is shown below, as you can see, QT Creator created CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS with `-MDd`. Which obviously created the mismatch.

```
CC            = cl
CXX           = cl
DEFINES       = -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zi -MDd -W3 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 /Fddebug\testbed.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\testbed.vc.pdb $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I..\testbed -I. -I..\testbed\libxsd -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\..\..\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc 
LINKER        = link
LFLAGS        = /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'"
LIBS          = C:\Users\intellitix\Documents\testbed\libxsd\lib\xerces-c_static_3d.lib /LIBPATH:C:\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\lib C:\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\lib\Qt5Cored.lib 
QMAKE         = C:\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe
```

Excerpt from `testbed.pro`
As you can see the library is full path NOT the CMAKE style with -L and -l (which makes problems when linking win32 libraries by Visual Studio)

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/xerces-c_static_3.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/xerces-c_static_3d.lib
else:unix: LIBS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/xerces-c_static_3.lib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/libxsd
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/libxsd

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/libxerces-c_static_3.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/libxerces-c_static_3d.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/xerces-c_static_3.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/xerces-c_static_3d.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libxsd/lib/libxerces-c_static_3.a
```

So my question is,

-Even though the the lib is asked to be linked statically, why QT Creator is complaining it is not compatible with `-MDd`, which is dynamic linking. (I tried putting the flag in `.pro` file, but it gets overridden)

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += /MTd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MTd
```

(`cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MTd' with '/MDd'`)

-Tried manually changing `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` in `Makefile.Debug` but that created even more problems since QMake now tries to link every dependent library statically. Isn't there a way to just static link one library and everything else as dynamic in QT Creator?

Using - 
VS2017,
QT Creator 4.8,
QT 5.9,
msvc2015 32bit,
xerces-c-3.1.4

btw, if linked to dynamic libraries (with lib and dll), everything works perfectly.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the static runtime libarary? You can't generally mix code compiled with different runtime libraries. There is no need to compile against the static runtime library in order to create a static library.

Comment: okay, let me try that. static library with dynamic runtime.

Comment: well, that worked half way, seems there are some problems with the library. unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall xercesc_3_1::Wrapper4InputSource::~Wrapper4InputSource(void)" Same for both for ctor and dtor. Any idea?

Comment: does this help https://codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2013-December/004161.html

Comment: i can see that defined in the pre-processor for static-debug/static-release.

Comment: to ensure that, i just removed the pre-processor from the hpp file, and made it like `class Wrapper4InputSource: public DOMLSInput` It looks like the cpp file never got compiled into the library!